# Need array of self, children and children childrens in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have a table like following

[image: Mysql table with parent ids]

well,here in this table every user has a parent user,then if we select a user then its id ,children ids and children childrens ids should return as array.I need a query to get this values in rails with out using any gem.Thanx for your help:->

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class User << ActiveRecord::Base      
  def self.build_tree(reverse=false)
    g = Array.new    
    self.find(:all).each do |p|           
        if reverse
        g << [p.id,p.parent]            
        else
        g << [p.parent,p.id]            
        end
    end
    g
  end
  def self.subordinates(man_id)
    g = self.build_tree false       
    g.map{|i| i[1] if i[0]==man_id.to_i}.compact    
  end
  def self.superiors(user_id)
     g = self.build_tree true            
     g.map{|i| i[1] if i[0]==user_id.to_i}.compact     
  end
end
```

When call either **Superiors(parents)** or **Subordinates(childrends)** it will gives required result 
Ex:- **[2,4,6,8]**  
If you want to get either **children->childrends** or **parent->parents** just do **iterate** call function **either superior or subordinates** until get the **nil or []** array .

Answer (score 1):

You are stranding into SQL anti-pattern. Performing operations on trees constructed like that is very inefficient. I don't say, that you should use a gem for that, but consider using some smarter method of keeping this data (searching for `sql tree structure` should yield some meaningful results).

Query you are looking for needs two self joins:

```
SELECT t1.id user_ids, t2.id children_ids, t3.id children_children_ids FROM users t1 
  LEFT JOIN users t2 ON t2.parent = t1.id
  LEFT JOIN users t3 ON t3.parent = t2.id
```

On the other hand, if your rails models have defined self-relation, you could easily write:

```
user.children #=> (array of children)
user.children.flat_map(&:children) #=> (array of grandchildren)
```

Definition of this relation should look like:

```
class User << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children, class_name: User, foreign_key: 'parent'
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much.but,Not even in a single query,I need a result for above situation.

Comment: Query I provided should solve your problem, have you tried it?

Comment: SELECT t1.id, t2.id, t3.id FROM table users 
  LEFT JOIN table t2 ON t2.parent = t1.id
  LEFT JOIN table t3 ON t3.parent = t2.id

Error in query: Syntax error near 'table users LEFT JOIN table t2 ON t2.parent = t1.id LEFT JOIN table t3 ON' at line 1

Comment: I got this while running :-<

Comment: You need to change lowercase `table` to name of your table (I believe it's `users`)

Comment: I am a bit confused about this,I have a only table that is users which I mentioned above.How can it check the ids and parents.can you please explain me in brief.

Comment: I have updated query, so that it might be easier to read. In first column, you have user_id. If you want to find data for single user just add `WHERE t1.id = user_id`. Second column contain ids of user's children, whilst third grandchildren.